# Jquery Slider slide on upper side countinuesly

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to create a slider that slide upper side continuously and with arrow button on and bottom Here i use this code but this not slide on upper slide

```
 <script class="secret-source">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
        animtype      : 'slide',
        height        : 320,
        width         : 620,
        responsive    : true,
        randomstart   : true
      });

    });
  </script>
```

with bjqs.1.3.min.js

i can't upload my image here now

Image is demo of my slider pls anyone can help to find this slider me

Comment: `<script class="secret-source">` ???

Answer (score 0):

please try jquery-ui slider link is https://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical

and code is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Vertical slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      value: 60,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
  <label for="amount">Volume:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="slider-vertical" style="height:200px;"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is not my answer i can't upload my pic here right now
pls visit makaan.com and see in left side Featured Projects slider pls

Comment: or you can use this link http://www.typicallyspanish.com/royalslider/templates/simple-vertical/

Comment: i'll send you image in your inbox

Comment: hi please see last example on this link http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified